# Note.py too many values expected

Tags: python

This is the command for the readall in my note.py module:

```
 if used_prefix and cmd == "readall" and self.getAccess(user) >= 1:
  try:
    if notes.check(user.name) == True:
      t = user.name.title()+" these are all your notes:<br><br>"
      for l in notes.getall(user.name):
        print(l)
        for sender, message, notetime in l:
          t += "From %s: %s (%s)" % (sender.title(), msg, stamp.LongTimeStampFull(notetime))
      room.message(t, True)
    else:
      room.message("Your inbox is empty! ;D")
  except:
    room.message((str(sys.exc_info()[1])))
```

`notes.getall(user.name)` is equivalent to `notes.database[user.name][:]`

The database uses a list inside of a list.

So I keep getting this error on my `note.py` every time I use the command.

```
too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

On the line:

```
for sender, msg, notetime in l:
```

Also when printing l:

```
['charles', 'testing this', 1260046789] ['charles', 'this is a test', 1230056545]
```

Comment: In what line are you getting that error?

Comment: Also, what version of python are you using?

Comment: Post the trace stack please.

Comment: That line is expecting a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) with three elements. You're giving it either a tuple with fewer than three elements, or not a tuple at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the edit where you show what is printed by `print(l)`, it seems your problem is that you're expecting `l` to have more than one "row" (i.e. be a list of lists), but it does not (it is a list of strings). You can solve this many ways, but here is one:

```
for l in notes.getall(user.name):
    sender, message, notetime = l
    t += "From %s: %s (%s)" % (sender.title(), msg, stamp.LongTimeStampFull(notetime))
```

As an example:

```
>>> a = ['test','test2','test3']
>>> b,c,d = a
>>> b
'test'
>>> c
'test2'
>>> d
'test3'
```

Alternatively, you can convert the list of strings into a list of lists:

```
>>> for b,c,d in [a]:
...  print(b,c,d)
...
test test2 test3
```